# PHP Laravel moltin cart paypal issue

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, paypal, laravel-5

I'm using laravel moltin shopping cart package. And I have been following this tutorial so far : http://jslim.net/blog/2014/09/19/integrate-paypal-sdk-into-laravel-4/

when I use the same code the code works perfectly but whenever I keep my own items on the cart, it shows an error : " Got Http response code 400 when accessing api.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment. "

Here is my code, currently I have commented out the static items, instead I'm using moltin package. Link : https://github.com/moltin/laravel-cart

```
public function postPayment()
    {

        $cart = new Cart(new Session, new Cookie);

        $payer = new Payer();
        $payer->setPaymentMethod('paypal');

//        $item_1 = new Item();
//        $item_1->setName('Item 1') // item name
//        ->setCurrency('USD')
//            ->setQuantity(2)
//            ->setPrice('15'); // unit price
//
//        $item_2 = new Item();
//        $item_2->setName('Item 2')
//            ->setCurrency('USD')
//            ->setQuantity(4)
//            ->setPrice('7');
//
//        $item_3 = new Item();
//        $item_3->setName('Item 3')
//            ->setCurrency('USD')
//            ->setQuantity(1)
//            ->setPrice('21');

        // add item to list
        $item_list = new ItemList();
        $item_list->setItems($cart->contents(true));

        $amount = new Amount();
        $amount->setCurrency('USD')
            ->setTotal($cart->total(false));

        $transaction = new Transaction();
        $transaction->setAmount($amount)
            ->setItemList($item_list)
            ->setDescription('Your transaction description');

        $redirect_urls = new RedirectUrls();
        $redirect_urls->setReturnUrl(URL::route('payment.status'))
            ->setCancelUrl(URL::route('payment.status'));

        $payment = new Payment();
        $payment->setIntent('Sale')
            ->setPayer($payer)
            ->setRedirectUrls($redirect_urls)
            ->setTransactions(array($transaction));

        $payment->create($this->_api_context);


        foreach($payment->getLinks() as $link) {
            if($link->getRel() == 'approval_url') {
                $redirect_url = $link->getHref();
                break;
            }
        }

        // add payment ID to session
        Session::put('paypal_payment_id', $payment->getId());

        if(isset($redirect_url)) {
            // redirect to paypal
            return Redirect::away($redirect_url);
        }

        return Redirect::route('original.route')
            ->with('error', 'Unknown error occurred');
    }
```

I'm getting this error :

```
stdClass Object
(
    [name] => MALFORMED_REQUEST
    [message] => Incoming JSON request does not map to API request
    [information_link] => https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#MALFORMED_REQUEST
    [debug_id] => 8df76ef7377bc
)
```

While using static items it works but for this it doesn't work. Any help ?

Thanks in advance!! :-)